# Sublime API missing

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, fedora

I try to install 'Sublime Text 3' on Fedora 21 from official site, but when I execute "sublime.py" it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sublime.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sublime_api
ImportError: No module named sublime_api
```

but in "sublime.py" has:

```
import sublime_api
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to "execute" `sublime.py`, it gets loaded by Sublime Text internally where the `sublime_api` module is provided by the C++ integration.

There should be some other executable which will load the real application.